# Retrieve tuple from string

Tags: scala

I have the following input string:

```
"0.3215,Some(0.5123)"
```

I would like to retrieve the tuple `(0.3215,Some(0.5123))` with: `(BigDecimal,Option[BigDecimal])`.

Here is one of the thing I tried so far:

```
"\\d+\\.\\d+,Some\\(\\d+\\.\\d+".r findFirstIn iData match {
  case None => Map[BigDecimal, Option[BigDecimal]]()
  case Some(s) => {
    val oO = s.split(",Some\\(")
    BigDecimal.valueOf(oO(0).toDouble) -> Option[BigDecimal](BigDecimal.valueOf(lSTmp2(1).toDouble))
  }
}
```

Using a `Map` and transforming it into a tuple.

When I try directly the tuple I get an `Equals` or an `Object`.

Must miss something here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has several issues, but the big one seems to be that the `case None` side of the match returns a `Map` but the `Some(s)` side returns a `Tuple2`.  `Map` and `Tuple2` unify to their lowest-common-supertype, `Equals`, which is what you're seeing.

I think this is what you're trying to achieve?

```
val Pattern = "(\\d+\\.\\d+),Some\\((\\d+\\.\\d+)\\)".r
val s = "0.3215,Some(0.5123)"
s match {
  case Pattern(a,b) => Map(BigDecimal(a) -> Some(BigDecimal(b)))
  case _ => Map[BigDecimal, Option[BigDecimal]]()
}
// Map[BigDecimal,Option[BigDecimal]] = Map(0.3215 -> Some(0.5123))
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about `regex` extractor; now I do. This fits. As an alternative, can I return an empty `tuple`?

Comment: A tuple can't be "empty" in the same way as, e.g., a list.  A `List` with no elements is still a `List`, but a `Tuple2` always has to have two elements.  The behavior I think you'd want is to return an `Option`, either `Some((a,b))` or `None`.